# How is $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{in\theta}e^{-ik\theta} d\theta = \delta_{n, k}$?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

I'm self-studying the text [*Harmonic Analysis: From Fourier to Wavelets*](https://bookstore.ams.org/view?ProductCode=STML/63) and on page 10 the formula for calculating Fourier coefficients
$$
\hat{f}(n) = a_{n}
$$
is derived. The part that I'm confused at is that it's shown that the following equality holds:
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{in\theta}e^{-ik\theta} d\theta = \delta_{n, k}
$$
where
$$
\delta_{n,k} = 1, \space \text{if} \space  k = n \space \text{and} \space 0, \space \text{if} \space k \neq n
$$

I understand why it's $1 $ when $n = k$ as it's simply $$ \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{0} d\theta \implies \frac{1}{2\pi} (\pi - (-\pi)) \implies 1 $$ but I can't seem to catch why it's zero when $n $ and $k$ are not equal. When I evaluate the integral, I get the following:

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i(n-k)\theta} d\theta \implies \frac{1}{2\pi i(n-k)} e^{i (n-k) (\pi - (-\pi))} \implies \frac{1}{2 \pi i(n-k)} e^{2 \pi i (n-k)} \neq 0
$$

Could someone please give me a **hint** on what I'm doing wrong or what I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: you are misevaluating that last integral

Comment: Your $e^{i (n-k) (\pi - (-\pi))}$ should be 
$e^{i (n-k)\pi}-e^{i (n-k)(-\pi)}.$

Comment: @AnneBauval ah, darn it. So it'll be 0 because that'll be the $sin(x \pi)$ due to Eurler's formula. It's been a few years since I've had to do integrals by hand...
Thank you and thank you, @peterag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there is a careless calculation in the last displayed formula.
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i(n-k)\theta} d\theta = \frac{1}{2\pi i(n-k)} e^{i (n-k) \pi}-\frac{1}{2\pi i(n-k)} e^{i (n-k) (-\pi)}$$

Secondly, we usually consider $n$ and $k$ are integers. In this case, it's zero. If not, let $n=1$, $k=\frac12$. You will find it's not zero.

Comment: Yep and yes, I assumed in the context of the question that n and k are indeed integers!